# Access file present in app service in azure using powershell(access kudu using powershell)

Tags: powershell, azure, kudu

Is there any way to access app service kudo using powershell.
Scenario: "https://webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net" App service in azure has D:\home\site\wwwroot\xyz.config and I want to change some content in xyz.config using powershell which now I am doing by manually accessing https://webapp.scm.azurewebsites.net and selecting powersell in kudu and running the command.

Now I want to do same using TFS job. For that I need command with which I can access app service path(D:\home\site\wwwroot) where xyz.config will be present instead of manually going and giving command.